# how to pass info from one widget to another in kv kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I want to set the text of a label when a button is pressed, the problem being they are son separate screens and therefore in separate widgets in the kv file. The code i have to change this is:

```
<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: player_name

        Button:
            text: "Continue"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "screen2"
                root.ids.final_playername.text=player_name.text
<ScreenTwo>:
    GridLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Player"
                id: final_playername
```

The error i get from this is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\Desktop\python exp\noughts and crosses kivy sm\nandx.py", line 36, in <module>
     nandxApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8146)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12816)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\Rayne\Desktop\python exp\noughts and crosses kivy sm\nandx.kv", line 51, in <module>
     root.ids.final_playername.text=player_name.text
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:12654)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

In the .py file i have the minimum with the classes for the screens, i´m trying to keep it simple under advice and do it all in the kv file. Can anyone help a newbie python learner to set this up? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the snippet and example below for details.

## Snippet

```
Button:
    size_hint: (.2, .08)
    text: "Continue"
    on_release:
        root.manager.ids.screen_two.ids.final_playername.text = player_name.text
        root.manager.current = "screen2"
```

## Example

### nandxApp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set("graphics", "width", "400")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "570")
Config.set("graphics", "borderless", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("kivy", "window_icon", "nyc.ico")


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ScreenOne(Screen, Widget):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen, Widget):
    pass


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass


class nandxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Noughts and Crosses"
        return Manager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nandxApp().run()
```

### nandx.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Manager>:
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two

    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen1"
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: (.5, .5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.6}
        rows: 3
        padding: 20

        Label:
            size_hint: (.2, .2)
            text: "Please enter\nyour name:"
            font_size: 30
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        TextInput:
            size_hint: (.2, .06)
            cursor_blink: True
            font_size: 20
            multiline: 0
            id: player_name

        Button:
            size_hint: (.2, .08)
            text: "Continue"
            on_release:
                root.manager.ids.screen_two.ids.final_playername.text = player_name.text
                root.manager.current = "screen2"

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "screen2"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.size
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("TopLeft")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("TopMiddle")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("TopRight")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("CenterLeft")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("CenterMiddle")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("CenterRight")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("BottomLeft")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("BottomMiddle")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("blank.png")
            # on_release: root.methodforbuttonpress ("BottomRight")

        Button:
            background_normal: ("x.png")

        GridLayout:
            rows: 2

            Label:
                text: "top label"

            Label:
                text: "bottom label"

        Button:
            background_normal: ("circle.png")

        GridLayout:
            rows: 2

            Label:
                text: "Player"
                id: final_playername

            Label:
                text: "Score:"

        Label:
            text: ""

        GridLayout:
            rows: 2

            Label:
                text: "Computer"

            Label:
                text: "Score:"


<ScreenThree>:
    name: "screen3"
```

### Output

[image: Screen2 with Player's Name]

Comment: Can you explain a bit where the error was in the question and how you fixed the problem in your code? Also it seems to me that your code you posted is larger than it needed to be, making it harder to get to the root of your fix. Maybe you could edit that a bit down or is really all of the code necessary?

Comment: Thank you very much ikolim, you solved my problem perfectly, i was clearly overcomplicating things. I guess you´ve been reading my previous posts to get all the code since i tried to post the minimum possible this time around. Thanks again!